# How to get selected value from 2 different comboboxes to show inside 1 textbox or lable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Hello I need to have the selected value from 2 different combo boxes display inside a textbox or label. I've tried this code

```
int i = (int)comboBox1.SelectItem - (int)comboBox2.SelectedItem;
i += int;
{
  textBox1.Text = i.ToString
}
```

That code is not doing anything at all, besides the fact that I don't know where to place the code. I tried a different code inside the `SelectedIndexChanged` of one of the combo boxes but it will work for that specific `comboBox` only not for both.

```
for (int i = 0; i < comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
  textBox1.Text = comboBox1.Text;

}
```

I would really appreciate any help I can get. Thank you all.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what is in each combobox and what you expect on the label.

Answer (score 1):

A Solution would be to have a button and two comboBoxes and a label in the form. When you press the button the texts selected from the comboBoxes get added and then the text in the label changes. Here is the form
[image]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //make sure that an item is selected
        if(comboBox1.SelectedItem != null &&
            comboBox2.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            //treat these like integers
            //label1.Text = Convert.ToString((Int32.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()) + (Int32.Parse(comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()))));

            //treat them like strings
            label1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }


    }
```

After selecting an item for both combo Boxes you can then click the button and the results will get added to each other like so
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Only problem is, I don't need the value from the comboboxes to be summarized inside the textbox. I need the same exact values to display side by side. In your example it would be 13 instead of 4

Comment: then uncomment the code for treating them like strings and comment the code for treating them like integers. I have edited the code for you if you want to try it

Comment: The solution would be to use the same event handler for both ComboBox controls, check the `SelectdItem` of both for null (as you're doing), then cast to the actual type that the `SelectdItem` contains. You should ask the OP if the ComboBoxes have been filled with `int` values or strings representing integers.

Comment: pabolo12 Thank you, so much! your code worked perfectly. You are awesome!

Comment: @Yorelis,It seems that your question has been solved, you can click '✔' to accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the working code to a Backgroundworker.

You can find the backgroundworker in the toolbox in the designer.

Add the code that works for you to this event :

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
```

You can double click on the backgroundworker in the designer to directly create this event.

Answer (score 0):

it's Easy

```
  public New_Project()
  {
     {
       InitializeComponent();

     if(comboBox1.Text==""&&comboBox2.Text=="")
     {

     }
     else
     {

     textbox1.Text= comboBox1.Text + comboBox2.Text ;

     }
```